# Event Handler Not Called When Command Is Dispatched from Saga

Tags: java, event-handling, axon

I've got a chain of `CommandHandler`, `EventSourcingHandler` and `EventHandler` that all get invoked as expected when the command `Foo` is dispatched directly. The same command does not cause the same `EventHandler` to be called if it is dispatched from within a `Saga` or common `EventHandler`.

Unfortunately I can not disclose the actual code, but here is an illustration of what happens:

[image: Illustration of the issue]

The `EventHandler` not being called only takes the event as argument, no `@MetaData` annotated arguments or similar. It is responsible for writing to the read model, which the `@SagaEventHandler` needs to continue its execution. At this point the process fails because the read model has not been updated yet, because the `EventHandler` has not been called.

What could be the issue here? Using Axon 4.3.1.

Configuration:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2020 divine Cloud Services Ltd.
 * All rights reserved
 *
 * All information contained herein is and remains the property of
 * divine Cloud Services Ltd. The intellectual and technical concepts
 * contained herein are proprietary to divine Cloud Services Ltd. and
 * may be protected by trade secret or copyright law. Dissemination
 * of this information or reproduction of this material is strictly prohibited
 * unless prior written permission is obtained from divine Cloud Services Ltd.
 */

package engineering.divine.infrastructure.conf;

import engineering.divine.artefact.model.meta.ArtefactDefinition;
import engineering.divine.artefact.ports.ArtefactDefinitionRepository;
import engineering.divine.infrastructure.persistence.BinarySerialiser;
import engineering.divine.infrastructure.persistence.DefaultArtefactDefinitionRepository;
import engineering.divine.infrastructure.persistence.graph.GraphEventStorageEngine;
import engineering.divine.infrastructure.persistence.graph.database.GraphManager;
import engineering.divine.infrastructure.security.interceptors.AuditCommandDispatchInterceptor;
import engineering.divine.integration.github.GitHubCommandHandler;
import engineering.divine.integration.github.GitHubQueryHandler;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandBus;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.CommandMessage;
import org.axonframework.commandhandling.SimpleCommandBus;
import org.axonframework.common.transaction.TransactionManager;
import org.axonframework.config.Configurer;
import org.axonframework.config.EventProcessingConfigurer;
import org.axonframework.eventhandling.PropagatingErrorHandler;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.EventSourcingRepository;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.SnapshotTriggerDefinition;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.Snapshotter;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStorageEngine;
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStore;
import org.axonframework.messaging.interceptors.BeanValidationInterceptor;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.Repository;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryBus;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.QueryMessage;
import org.axonframework.queryhandling.SimpleQueryBus;
import org.axonframework.spring.eventsourcing.SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Configuration
public class AxonConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Value("${engineering.divine.snapshot.threshold:30}")
    private int snapshotThreshold;

    @Bean
    public CommandBus commandBus(TransactionManager transactionManager,
                                 AuditCommandDispatchInterceptor auditCommandDispatchInterceptor,
                                 BeanValidationInterceptor<CommandMessage<?>> validationInterceptor) {

        SimpleCommandBus commandBus = SimpleCommandBus.builder()
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();

        commandBus.registerDispatchInterceptor(auditCommandDispatchInterceptor);
        commandBus.registerDispatchInterceptor(validationInterceptor);

        return commandBus;
    }

    @Bean
    public QueryBus queryBus(TransactionManager transactionManager,
                             BeanValidationInterceptor<QueryMessage<?, ?>> validationInterceptor) {
        SimpleQueryBus queryBus = SimpleQueryBus.builder()
                .transactionManager(transactionManager)
                .build();

        queryBus.registerDispatchInterceptor(validationInterceptor);

        return queryBus;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    EventStore eventStore(GraphManager graphManager, BinarySerialiser serialiser) {
        EventStorageEngine storageEngine = GraphEventStorageEngine
                .builder()
                .graphManager(graphManager)
                .serialiser(serialiser)
                .build();

        return EmbeddedEventStore.builder()
                .storageEngine(storageEngine)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    Snapshotter snapshotter(EventStore eventStore) {
        SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean factoryBean = new SpringAggregateSnapshotterFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        factoryBean.setEventStore(eventStore);
        factoryBean.setExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    SnapshotTriggerDefinition snapshotTriggerDefinition(Snapshotter snapshotter) {
        return new EventCountSnapshotTriggerDefinition(snapshotter, snapshotThreshold);
    }

    @Bean
    ArtefactDefinitionRepository artefactDefinitionRepository(EventStore eventStore) {
        Repository<ArtefactDefinition> delegate = EventSourcingRepository
                .builder(ArtefactDefinition.class)
                .eventStore(eventStore)
                .build();

        return new DefaultArtefactDefinitionRepository(delegate);
    }

    @Bean
    BeanValidationInterceptor<CommandMessage<?>> beanValidationCommandInterceptor() {
        return new BeanValidationInterceptor();
    }

    @Bean
    BeanValidationInterceptor<QueryMessage<?, ?>> beanValidationQueryInterceptor() {
        return new BeanValidationInterceptor();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(EventProcessingConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.usingSubscribingEventProcessors();
        configurer.registerDefaultListenerInvocationErrorHandler(configuration -> PropagatingErrorHandler.instance());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configure(Configurer configurer, GitHubCommandHandler commandHandler, GitHubQueryHandler queryHandler) {
        configurer.registerCommandHandler(c -> commandHandler);
        configurer.registerQueryHandler(c -> queryHandler);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

Abbreviated call chain:

1. The initial command gets received via HTTP request.

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
  ...
  @RequestMapping("/doA")
  public CompletableFuture<Void> doA(@RequestBody CommandA cmdA) {
    ...
    // Do something else before cmdA
    CommandX cmdX = new CommandX();
    commandGateway.sendAndWait(cmdX);
    ...
    commandGateway.sendAndWait(cmdA);
  }
}
```

2. Command A spawns a new `@Aggregate`.

```
@Aggregate
public class MyFooAggregate {
  @CommandHandler
  public MyFooAggregate(CommandA cmd, MetaData metaData) {
    apply(new FooCreated(), metaData);
  }
  ...
}
```

3. A `@Saga` picks up on the `FooCreated` event and issues a new command. There is no distinct configuration class for sagas.

```
@Saga
public class MySaga {

  // (end will not be the same as start in the future)
  @StartSaga
  @EndSaga
  @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "id")
  public void handleFooCreated(FooCreated event, @MetaDataValue("valueX") String valueX, CommandGateway commandGateway) {
    CommandB cmdB = new CommandB();
    ...
    Map<String, Object> meta = new HashMap<>();
    meta.put("valueX", valueX);

    CommandMessage<CommandB> cmdMsg = GenericCommandMessage.asCommandMessage(cmdB);
    cmdMsg.withMetaData(meta);

    // because I don't need to wait for the result, I'll just "send" it
    commandGateway.send(cmdMsg);
  }
}
```

4. A dedicated command handler which is not an aggregate takes care of command B. It uses an interface `MyProvider` for which the implementation dispatches another command. The handler has been registered in the configuration (see `AxonConfig`).

```
@Component
public class CommandHandler {

  MyProvider provider;

  @CommandHandler
  public void doB(CommandB cmdB) {
    ...
    provider.provideMeWithSomething();
    ...
  }
}
```

5. The implementation of `MyProvider` finally dispatches command C.

```
@Component
public class MyDefaultProvider implements MyProvider {

  @Override
  public Object provideMeWithSomething() {
    CommandC cmdC = new CommandC();
    commandGateway.sendAndWait(cmdC);
    ...
  }  

}
```

6. Command C spawns a new `@Aggregate`. The event dispatched from the creation of this aggregate is the one that is being handled in the `@EventSourcingHandler`, but does not find its way to the `@EventHandler`.

```
@Aggregate
public class MyBarAggregate {
  @CommandHandler
  public MyBarAggregate(CommandC cmdC) {
    apply(new BarCreated());
  }
  ...
}
```

7. The `@EventSourcingHandler` in the same class `MyBarAggregate` gets invoked, but not the common `@EventHandler` responsible for writing the read model.

```
@Aggregate
public class MyBarAggregate {
  ...
  @EventSourcingHandler
  public handleBarCreated(BarCreated event) {
    // DOES get called
    ...
  }
}

@Component
public class EventHandler {
  @EventHandler
  public handleBarCreated(BarCreated event) {
    // DOES NOT get called
    ...
  }
}
```

Both event handlers do however get called when `CommandC` gets dispatched directly (like e.g. from within a `@RestController`). Other `@EventHandler`s do get called, only this specific instance does not in this specific case.

Comment: Hi @Double M, this scenario should work without any problems. To try to help you with that, can we at least see what is your configuration in general? Specially around the Event Processors. Other than that, knowing which event store and message broker you are using would definitely help.

Comment: @LucasCampos Thank you, I have added the config and further information above - could it be a timing problem (order of execution)?

Comment: Interesting to see you've built your own `GraphEventStorageEngine`. Would be interested to learn more about this if your time allows it.

Comment: @Steven Sure thing, I've sent you a direct message on Twitter.

Comment: Noticed @DoubleM, thanks!

Comment: My apologies, but I envision not to be able to help you in a timely manner due to some personal matters. I've notified some of my peers, so potentially somebody else will help you further. Thanks for the additional information thus far!

Comment: Hi @DoubleM. I've tried to reproduce the situation locally, sticking as closely as possible to the same process. Instead of using the custom GraphEventStorageEngine, I have used an In-Memory EventStorateEngine implementation. It just worked as expected.
To exclude it's the GraphEventStorageEngine, could you configure another instance, to see what happens? Also, can you confirm that the command emitted from the Saga is completed successfully?

Comment: It's been sometime now, but I'm still curious whether this issue is still a problem in your environment. Would you be able to share something on this DoubleM?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I was trying to conceive where the problem could lie, thinking about the type of `EventProcessor` you are using. As shown on your configuration (thanks for adding that), you are using the `SubscribingEventProcessor`.

This essentially means the same thread publishing the command (the Saga in this case) is (at least should be) invoking the `@EventHandler` annotated method, as that's just how the `SubscribingEventProcessor` works. Especially if you're doing a `CommandGateway#sendAndWait(Object)`, that'll mean the thread locking your Saga is also locking an aggregate to handle to command, and would be in charge of providing the same event to the `SubscribingEventProcessor` of said event handler (which isn't being invoked).

So, secondly, how are you dispatching the command? It's fine you cannot share the exact code, but sample/pseudocode should be doable right?
Thirdly, how's the Saga being configured? Just regular Spring auto config with the `@Saga` stereotype, or is there a distinct configuration class in place?

To be honest, I am still hard pressed to understand why said `SubscribingEventProcessor` in charge of the `@EventHandler` annotated function is not invoked. Could you confirm whether **all** event handlers which are part of this `SubscribingEventProcessor` are not invoked, or if it's just this one event handling class?

Comment: I have extended my question with pseudocode and while doing so noticed that there is nested command dispatching going on. `CommandC` is dispatched within the execution of `CommandB`. I would expect that all events caused by the nested `CommandC` are handled before the execution of `CommandB` continues (with a `SubscribingEventProcessor`), is this the case?